# Partitioned Single Solution Model for Larger System

Tags: c#, architecture, visual-studio-2012, ef-code-first, projects-and-solutions

I was never sure if multi-solution system was possible in `Visual Studio` but now after reading [Structuring Solutions and Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817674.aspx) and [Walkthrough: Adding an existing Visual Studio solution to another solution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/habibh/archive/2009/06/24/walkthrough-adding-an-existing-visual-studio-solution-to-another-solution.aspx) i am fully convinced. Its a shame the msdn article was written a while back and i couldn't find a follow up to our latest technologies (Visual Studios 2010/2012).

Anyways, i am very interested to try out **Partitioned Single Solution Model for Larger Systems** explained in the `MSDN` article but i thought before i commit to it, i should try and do a little bit more research. Now when i create a new mvc application, i usually create 3 projects in it (`Domain, UnitTests and WebUI`).

Here is an example of what i would like to do:

```
ParentSolution
----Parent.Domain
----Parent.UnitTests
----Parent.WebUI

----ChildASolution
--------ChildA.Domain
--------ChildA.UnitTests
--------ChildA.WebUI

--------GrandChildASolution
------------GrandChildA.Domain
------------GrandChildA.UnitTests
------------GrandChildA.WebUI

----ChildBSolution
--------ChildB.Domain
--------ChildB.UnitTests
--------ChildB.WebUI
```

**First question:** Child solutions are inside the parent solution, but they do not depend on the parent solution. Grand child solution however, will be pulling some data from the child solution projects to function. Is this structure possible?

**Second question:** Can each of the solutions, including the parent solution have their own `ConnectionString`?

**Third question:** Can each of the solutions, including the parent solution have their own `Database`?

**Fourth question:** Will Membership users in Master solution have access to restricted actions in Child and GrandChild solutions, provided i add the dependencies?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `Areas`?

Comment: No `Areas` i went with `Partitioned Solution` explained in the article. I will learn more as i go forward

Comment: @Komengem, Why do you need to do this, Why not use projects simply....